# I am using log4js for logging the information. Want to print system logs. So how to do it?

Tags: protractor, log4js-node

I want to print the systems logs as its get printed using java and log4j.
However, i am not getting the way to write the system logs in protractor using log4js.

```
  log4js.configure({
    appenders: [
    {
      type: "clustered",
      appenders: [
        {
          type: "dateFile",
          filename: "log/access.log",
          pattern: "-yyyy-MM-dd",
          category: "http"
        },
        {
          type: "file",
          filename: "log/app.log",
          maxLogSize: 10485760,
          numBackups: 3
        },
        {
          type: "logLevelFilter",
          level: "ERROR",
          appender: {
            type: "file",
            filename: "log/errors.log"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/log go through this link.

Comment: It doesn't say how to use log4js to print system logs in a file

Comment: you want browser logs? or what do you mean by System logs?

Comment: System logs means the exception which are printing or all which ever is printing on the console.

Like we have the same as Root Logger in Log4J there we generate system logs